# jquery access checkbox by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have checkboxes using `name="item[]"`, I can access them by using id, but the problem is they all have to have unique ids and class names. Is there any way I can access them by just the name property alone? That is the only thing they have in common. I have used this code, which works, but applies the same to the 2nd group of checkboxes. I have tried `.attr('item[]')`, but I am unsure if the array is messing things up. Ideas?

```
$( 'input:checkbox:checked' ).length;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use jquery selector:

`$('input[name="item[]"]:checkbox:checked').length;`

Also you can do what you want with your elements by for each loop:

```
$('input[name="item[]"]:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    //do something
});
```

It will read all elements with this selector one-by-one and return in `this` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$( 'input[name="item[]"]:checkbox:checked' ).length;
```